# PHP printing something wrong

Tags: php

I have the following php line :

```
<?php echo "?page=" . $selectedImage + 1 ."&pid=5"."&type=". $type . "&special=" . $special; ?>
```

the line above is inside a

and the link generated is :

XXXXXX.com/1&pid=5&type=AD23&special=first

and it is not printing "?page", any idea why ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Uzr43P

Comment: Due to same operator precedence and left associativity, effectively you're trying to do `<?php echo (("?page=" . $selectedImage) + 1) ."&pid=5"."&type=". $type . "&special=" . $special; ?>`.... concatenate `?page=` and `$selectedImage`, then adding the result of that concatenation to the value `1` (which gives 1 because the concatenate value loose casts to 0 because it isn't a numeric), then concatenating that `1` with the rest of your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange behavior ... :(
but to fix it try this :

```
<?php echo "?page=" . (string)($selectedImage + 1) ."&pid=5" . "&type=" . $type . "&special=" . $special; ?>
```

Best Practice to format your string, is to use sprintf()

```
sprintf("?page=%d&pid=5&type=%s&special=%s", ($selectedImage + 1), $type, $special);
```

**EDIT**

```
Mystery Resolved 
/*
 PHP will try to create number by concatening the string '20' and the integer
 $i, so the operation will result to the integer 205
 after that, make addition operation => 210 
*/
$i = 5;
echo '20' . $i + 5;
```

What's happening in your case, is similar :)

Comment: Oscar ! it seems like casting a string on that worked, thanks :D

Comment: mark as solved !! :) you're welcome

Comment: That just does not make sense... the result of ($selectedImage +1) should automatically be treated as/cast to a string when appended via the . operator. Very strange.

Comment: MiDri, strongly agree with you, this is a strange behavior, and Halayem, thanks for the practice tip.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding brackets

```
<?php echo "?page=" . ($selectedImage + 1) ."&pid=5"."&type=". $type . "&special=" . $special; ?>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why that works?

Comment: the number is shown correctly but the ?page= isn't, i've tried your suggestion but the same result, i'l update the question, maybe i've skipped something

Comment: @andrewsi order of operations, + happens after . so: "?page=" . $selectedImage is added against 1 ."&pid=5"."&type=". $type . "&special=" . $special

Comment: @MiDri - I know. But this would be a better answer if there was an explanation in there as to why this is happening.

Comment: Actually, `+` and `.` are at the same level of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Which means they are handled left to right.

Comment: @MiDri - not quite as straightforward as that.... both have equal precedence, and it's the left associativity that makes the difference.... see my explanation in the comments to the OP's question